# Arraylist containing Integers and Strings

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I want to create a Arraylist which should contain Integers and Strings.. Is that possible?

I have created two Arraylist as given below:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intList.add(1);
    intList.add(2);

ArrayList<String> strList=new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("India");
    strList.add("USA");
    strList.add("Canada");
```

I want to put intList  & strList into a new ArrayList.

Can I do that?? If so, How??

Comment: Yeah, you can create an `ArrayList<Object>` but having said that, my advice for you is this: don't. Don't create Lists with mixed types since this suggests that your program design is broken and needs to be improved so that this sort of monster isn't needed.

Comment: Why you want to mix up two different types in a single ArrayList?

Comment: Are there any dependencies between this two Lists?

Comment: Any answer should also explain why this is a bad idea. I am -1 voting all that don't.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you want it for, we can suggest some better way of doing it.

Comment: Actually there is no dependencies. But as per requirement I asked to do that.

Comment: @user2648572 Can you please explain *why* you want to do it?

Comment: re `"But as per requirement..."` -- **whose** requirement? Please clarify why you are doing this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels instead of downvoting everybody, why not add an answer explaining it?

Comment: Just because you can do something, doesn't make it a good idea.  This sort of "solution" is highly unlikely to be a good idea and more likely you should implement a different one based on your actual requirements.  BTW +1 for a first question, it is ok.

Comment: Dude this `as per requirement` stuff stinks of homework!

Comment: @user000001: I cannot answer til the user justifies his reasoning for this need. Until then, all I ask is that answerers place a caveat in their answers stating that this is a bad idea. I don't find this unreasonable.

Comment: You've made a good choice of solutions (I think). 1+

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this as follows but have to give up on generics for the list container.

```
List<List> listOfMixedTypes = new ArrayList<List>();

ArrayList<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

listOfMixedTypes.add(listOfStrings);
listOfMixedTypes.add(listOfIntegers);
```

But, a better way would be to use a `Map` to keep track of the two lists since the compiler would no longer be able to prevent you from mixing types like putting a String into an Integer list.

```
Map<String, List> mapOfLists = new HashMap<String, List>();

mapOfLists.put("strings", listOfStrings);
mapOfLists.put("integers", listOfIntegers);

mapOfLists.get("strings").add("value");
mapOfLists.get("integers").add(new Integer(10));
```

Answer (score 8):

If it's avoidable, please avoid this list of Object type. Go for individual lists.

If not then you should go for type of `Object`

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

which accept all the type Objects, but have to take care while retrieving.

Checking the objects while retrieving

```
for (Object obj: list) {
    if (obj instanceof String){
        // this  is string 
    } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
       // this  is Integer 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Object> oList=new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: I can not understand why are you so angry?He is just asking a question and I give the right answer.Dangerous side of this solution is another issue.

Comment: I'm not angry. But I dislike bad advice given as answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *tagged sum types*: `Either<A, B>` is either `Left<A, B>` or `Right<A, B>`. In Java it will look like:

```
public interface Either<A, B>;
public class Left<A, B> implements Either<A, B> {
  public final A value;
  public Left(A value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
public class Right<A, B> implements Either<A, B> {
  public final B value;
  public Right(B value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

So, you can use `ArrayList<Either<Integer, String>>`.

```
for (Either<Integer, String> either : intsOrStrings) {
  if (either instanceof Left) {
    Integer i = ((Left<Integer, String>) either).value;
  } else if (either instanceof Right) {
    String s = ((Right<Integer, String>) either).value;
  }
}
```

This approach is more type-safe than using `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

I am providing you that example which is implement in my project inquiryhere.com [Click here to Visit](https://www.inquiryhere.com)

### java code...

```
public class hash_Map {
public HashMap<Integer, String> getQuestionTagWithId(int qId) throws SQLException{
    DatabaseConnection dc = new DatabaseConnection();
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        con = dc.getConnection();
        String sql = "select tag_id as unique_id,(select topic_name from topic where unique_id = question_topic_tag.tag_id)topic_name from question_topic_tag where question_id =?";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, qId);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            int questionTagId = rs.getInt("unique_id");
            String questionTag = rs.getString("topic_name");
            map.put(questionTagId, questionTag);
        }
    }catch(SQLException msg){
        throw msg;
    }finally{
          if(rs != null){
            try{
                rs.close();
            }catch(SQLException msg){

            }
        }
        if(ps != null){
            try{
                ps.close();
            }catch(SQLException msg){

            }
        }
        if(con != null){
            try{
                con.close();
            }catch(SQLException msg){

            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}}
```

### Jspbean

```
<jsp:useBean class="com.answer.hash_Map" id="SEO"  scope="page" />
```

### jstl code, I am working with jstl

```
 <c:forEach items="${SEO.getQuestionTagWithId(param.Id)}" var="tag" varStatus="loop">
                       ${tag.key}${tag.value}
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to print both at same time try 2D array

```
String[][] fruits = {{"Orange", "Lemon", "Grapes"},
                     {"Mango", "Melon", "Apples"}};
    int[][] prices = {{4, 6, 7},
                     {14, 3, 6}};
    int c = 0;
    for (String[] x : fruits) {
        c++;
        System.out.println(fruits[c - 1][c - 1] + " price is " + prices[c - 1][c - 1]);
    }
```